# NodeJS asynchronous/non-blocking io basic

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nonblocking, event-loop

Trying to get my head around a simple nodejs asynchronous way of handling i/o and a below simple snippet as an example leaves me in question marks.

```
    // Just to simulate an io (webservice call).
    var performRiskCheckViaWebservice = function(personPassportNumber, callback) {
        console.log("Risk check called for personPassportNumber: "+personPassportNumber);
        setTimeout(callback(personPassportNumber, "OK"), 5000);
    }

    function assessRisk(passportNumber) {
        performRiskCheckViaWebservice(passportNumber, function(passportNumber, status){
            console.log("Risk status of "+passportNumber+" is: "+status);
        })
    }

    assessRisk("1");
    assessRisk("2");
    assessRisk("3");
```

In the above simple code snippet, my expectation is to see:

```
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 1
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 2
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 3

And 5 seconds later:
Risk status of 1 is: OK
Risk status of 2 is: OK
Risk status of 3 is: OK
```

But the actual output is:

```
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 1
Risk status of 1 is: OK
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 2
Risk status of 2 is: OK
Risk check called for personPassportNumber: 3
Risk status of 3 is: OK
```

5 seconds later, the program halts.

What's wrong in my understanding?

Comment: As I realised it, setTimeout(callback(personPassportNumber, "OK"), 5000); instantly executes the callback function rather than scheduling it. How will I be able to pass values into the callback then?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I have to wrap the callback with an anonymous function inside the setTimeout(...). Here is the working version:

```
    // Just to simulate an io (webservice call).
    var performRiskCheckViaWebservice = function(personPassportNumber, callback) {
        console.log("Risk check called for personPassportNumber: "+personPassportNumber);
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(personPassportNumber, "OK")
        }, 5000);
    }

    function assessRisk(passportNumber) {
        performRiskCheckViaWebservice(passportNumber, function(personPassportNumber, status){
            console.log("Risk status of "+personPassportNumber+" is: "+status);
        })
    }

    assessRisk("1");
    assessRisk("2");
    assessRisk("3");
```

Comment: True. In fact, he is calling the callback and passing its result to setTimeout(). Which could be valid if this where what he intended to do (but I think not) if that callback returned a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sync waterfall of your code :

```
sync assessRisk
sync performRiskCheckViaWebservice
sync console.log Risk.check
sync callback <== problem here
sync console.log Risk status
sync setTimeout 5000
```

so what you observe is normal.

you can replace

```
setTimeout(callback(personPassportNumber, "OK"), 5000);
```

by

```
setTimeout(callback.bind(null, personPassportNumber, "OK"), 5000);
```